# Position:absolute causes horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Absolutely positioned (side yellow advertisements) div's cause unwanted horizontal scrollbar when window is resized (size decreased) beyond them. Scrollbar should appear only when window is smaller than main `#container` and these advertisement div's should not affect the layout. It doesnt matter if they get covered.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='topbar'>
    <div id='menu'> <a href='#'>Link1</a>
 <a href='#'>Link2</a>
 <a href='#'>Link3</a>
 <a href='#'>Link4</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='pushfix'></div>
    <div id='ad_container'>
        <div id='ad1'>ad</div>
        <div id='ad2'>ad</div>
    </div>
Lorem ipsum placeholder text
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#topbar {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
}
#menu {
    width:250px;
    background-color:#B3B3B3;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
#menu a {
    color:#fff;
}
#container {
    height:100%;
    background-color:#808080;
    width:240px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#pushfix {
    height:40px;
}
#ad_container {
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
}
#ad_container div {
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
}
#ad1 {
    left:-105px;
}
#ad2 {
    right:-105px;
}
```

> **Exact layout replica: http://jsfiddle.net/8UkQA/**

Comment: whey not set the overflow in you css to hidden?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: setting `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element will prevent the user from being able to scroll to content within the body that spans beyond the height of their browser window.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements that expand beyond the boundaries of the `body` seem to cause scrollbars to appear, for some reason. You can remedy this by simply wrapping everything inside the body tag in a relatively-positioned div styled with `overflow: hidden;`. The absolutely positioned content that expands beyond the boundaries of this container won't cause scrollbars on the window.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8UkQA/1/

Comment: Just to clarify, if the absolutely position elements go past the boundary of `body` on the *top* or *left*, they won't cause scrollbars.

Comment: Firefox (maybe other browsers too) have a bug related to this approach. When you open anchor link on this page scrollbars will appear again.

Comment: I added body{ overflow: hidden; } to the page css style and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Adding it to the body wasn't working all the time for me. Adding it to the html element did the trick for me.

Comment: I found that adding `position: relative;` only fixes the issue when you add it to the closest parent element.

Answer (score 17):

I may like to further add, if the same problem is being faced and by using the solution suggested by @Aaron the page seems to not scroll then you can use axis specific version of the "`overflow`" attribute, as following,

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

This will only hide the content protruding on the right hand side (*or left hand side if website is RTL*) and not the vertical content.

Also to further enhance this method if the protruding content is appearing only at a certain resolution (as in my case), you can use css media query to restrict the behaviour.

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to give the child coordinates a.k.a. `top: 0; left: 0;`

Answer (score -5):

// need to disable `AutoScroll` first, otherwise disabling the horizontal scrollbar doesn't work

```
flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = false;
```

// disable `horizontal scrollbar`

```
flowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
```

// restore `AutoScroll`

```
flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.