# Body width 100% issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my `body` selector. When I make my windows smaller it doesn't keep the body width at 100%, and I don't have any clue why.

```
body
{
  margin:0px !important;
  background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

This is generating a footer bug when I make the window smaller because the body is not on the whole width.

I can't add pics to show because I don't have 10 rep, but you can check at this link and make the windows smaller:
http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/about.php?active=1

i dont want my website to be responsive i just want my body to be 100% on any resolution. here are the links of pics and problem i have when i make the window smaller: i.imgur.com/70sj43G.png i.imgur.com/OgMZVxa.png

Comment: Post pics to imgur and share URL

Answer (score 2):

You have widths set inside the body. For example your navigation has a width of 1060px as does your main_bg div.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually caused by `div#banner`, which has the following style:

```
 #banner {
   position: absolute;
   width: 150px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 1040px;
 }
```

Margin set to `1040px` together with `width: 150px` causes your banner to have overall width of `1190px`, that is wider than the rest of site.
I assume you've used `position: absolute` on your banner to avoid this problem, but this is not enough to make it work like you want.
You can read more about solution to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308257/positionabsolute-causes-horizontal-scrollbar).

*Note:*
The above solves your problem, but won't help making your site *responsive*.
If *responsive design* is your goal (you didn't say this, I'm just guessing that maybe it is), I'd recommend looking at some tutorials to get the basic rules etc.
There also are responsive frameworks like  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) that help making responsive websites.

Comment: i dont want my website to be responsive i just want my body to be 100% on any resolution. here are the links of pics and problem i have when i make the window smaller: http://i.imgur.com/70sj43G.png http://i.imgur.com/OgMZVxa.png

Comment: try the solution from the link I've posted, for me it works but I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The child divs are not set to fluid widths. If you change the CSS "width" to "max-width" you'll get a chance to see how the layout changes at different screen widths. There will definitely be further updates needed to your CSS, but this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onresize = function() {
   document.body.style.width = document.body.scrollWidth+"px";
}
```

This can help you, when the document is resized, this callback reset body width to 100% of document's width.