# Why does an absolutely positioned element take space in this side menu?

Tags: html, css

I am creating the following side menu with animation: [click](https://codepen.io/pavelDev/pen/PoemzaK)

We can see an unwanted horizontal scrollbar, which should not be according to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position),

> `absolute`
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and **no space** is
> created for the element in the page layout.

In the example above, the list of menu appears when you click on the checkbox and it has the class `.m-list`. `.m-list` has absolute positioning and relative positioning is set for its nearest parent(`.m-block`). I'm going to copy and paste these two classes

```
.m-block {
      width: 100%;
      background: gray;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      position: relative;
   }
   
   
   .m-list {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      background: silver;
      right: 0;
      width: auto;
      list-style-type: none; 
      transform: translateX(0%);
      transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
   }
```

**Q1:** Why does the horizontal scrollbar appear?

**Q2:** What is the most correct solution to prevent the appearance of a horizontal scrollbar?

I know 4 ways to solve this problem, but due to various reasons I do not want to use them:

1. If I change the absolute position to a fixed one, it does not generate a horizontal scrollbar, but the rule line with `top: 100%;` takes on a different meaning. In the original case, `top: 100%;` provides an offset from the blue stripe along its height.
2. Using JS is not available in this project
3. Using `overflow-x: hidden` on the top level of document will disable the scrollbar, which may be needed for content.
4. Moving the menu from the right side to the left will not result in a horizontal bar, however, this is an undesirable solution.

   ```
   .m-list {
      ...
      left: 0;
      transform: translateX(0%);
   }
   #m-toggle:checked ~ .m-list {
      ...
      transform: translateX(-100%);
   }
   ```

Comment: i think this link will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308257/positionabsolute-causes-horizontal-scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

I tried applying `overflow-x: hidden;` to `<body>`. and I was able to scroll down and hide the menu